# PayPal IPN does not add a data to my database. But it was working in the past

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have little donation webpage via PayPal. It was working fine, but few days ago it stopped working and I do not know why. I was searching the internet if PayPal IPN got some update or something like that and I found nothing.

When I am trying it on the sandbox account. Everything seems to work. It goes to the transaction, then return me to the return url. I see the transaction about the donation in the notifications of the sandbox account, but the part where it should put it in my database just does not work.

I have this code:
test.php where the form is to put donation details (name... etc):

```
                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-spoit2175143@business.example.com">

                    <!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
                    
                    <!-- Ostatní proměnné -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="donate_zruseno.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="donate_dokonceno.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="donate_test.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CZK">
```

My donate_test.php has this:

```
<?php
$DATABASE_HOST = 'HOST';
$DATABASE_USER = 'USER';
$DATABASE_PASS = 'PASS';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'DATABASE';

$pripojeni = new mysqli($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_donations';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Vyčteme nastavení z databáze.
    $sql_nastaveni = mysqli_query($pripojeni, "SELECT sandbox, webhook FROM podpora_nastaveni");
        while($db_nastaveni = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_nastaveni)) {
            $nastaveni_webhook = $db_nastaveni['webhook'];
            $sandbox = $db_nastaveni['sandbox'];
        }

//post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
//$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO podpora (datum, discord, email, castka, cenzura, zprava, platnost) VALUES (NOW(), 'discord,', 'test@test.cz', '0', 'ne', 'test', '2022-12-10')";
mysqli_query($pripojeni, $sql);

} else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {



}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

I tried put the mysqli_query in if !fp is OK, but still everything seems to be OK, but no new data in database.

I really do not know where can be error. Can you help me with it?

It seems to like the transaction do not go via the donate_test.php at all. If I run the donate_test.php the first SQL INSERT is added to the database (the !fp ofc not, because It does not went via PayPal).

Comment: Are you receiving IPN messages? Log them, log the result of the verification, and cross-reference with your Sandbox IPN history, https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/history.  In your initial test.php , `notify_url` should be a fully qualified URL including https:// and a domain.

Comment: Yes I see everything in the IPN history in the sandbox business acount. notify_url is with https://. When I test IPN simulator, everything went okay. But when I do that on the website. Nothing went threw. Like if the notify_url was not processed. I really do not know what is happening.

Comment: `name="notify_url" value="donate_test.php"` It's not so in your code. But anyway without logging what is occurring you will not be able to trace nor debug the problem..

Comment: Oh ye .. sorry, I just deleted it when I post it to hide the website's URL.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me, it works perfectly with subscriptions but it doesn't work with normal transactions like _xclick. In fact it doesn't even generate the IPN message

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).